# Unable to send strings with Axios using FormData using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios, form-data

I'm trying to send an input of file along with an input of text in a single request using Axios and FormData in Vue.js. I've read that it is very simple, just do :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('text', text);
axios.post('ajax.php', formData)
.then(function (response){
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

But that only works for some absurd reason if “text” is an integer. This is the HTML code that I'm using for the form :

```
<div v-for="(gallery, i) in galleryMeta">
    <form @submit.prevent="editData('gallery', gallery.Id, i)">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-12 pb-sm-0 pt-sm-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-sm-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column py-3 pl-sm-0 pl-4">
                    <h6 class="font-normal text-brand-primary pb-1 pl-md-0 pl-sm-4">Title:</h6>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-md-start justify-content-sm-center">
                        <input type="text" class="border-radius d-md-flex d-sm-none" v-model="gallery.Title">
                        <input type="text" class="border-radius w-75 d-md-none d-sm-flex d-none" v-model="gallery.Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-12 pb-sm-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-sm-end justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-sm-column pr-lg-0 pr-sm-3">
                    <label class="btn btn-brand-primary font-bold py-2 my-sm-0 my-2" for="file">EDIT</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp" @change="pickData">
                    <button class="btn btn-brand-secondary font-bold px-lg-5 px-3 py-2 my-2 mx-sm-0 mx-2" @click="editData('gallery', gallery.Id, i)">UPLOAD</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The form works just fine for everything else. This is the Vue.js code :

```
let app = Vue.createApp({
    data: function(){
        return{
            File: '',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        pickData: function (){
            this.File = event.target.files[0];
        },
        editData: function (requestSection, Id, i, Title){
            if(requestSection === 'gallery'){
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', this.File);
                formData.append('id', Id);
                formData.append('title', this.galleryMeta[i].Title);
                axios.post('ajax.php', formData, {
                    header: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
                .then(function (response){
                    console.log(response.data);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This is the ajax.php file to handle the Axios AJAX request :

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$request = $data->request;

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    $id = json_decode($_POST['id']);
    $title = json_decode($_POST['title']);
    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
}
?>
```

You may've noticed the 2 first lines in the PHP code. The reason for why they're there is that in the same PHP file I'm also handling other simple Axios POSTS requests by data binding, which all work properly. Although I believe that they do not cause any issues related to this, I'm including them just in case they do.

In the PHP file `$id` is defined properly, `$file` is defined properly however `$title` never is no matter what I do. After hours of intense troubleshooting, I've found that strings never make it past the Axios request, ever. If I change :

```
formData.append('title', this.galleryMeta[i].Title);
```

to

```
formData.append('title', '20');
```

It is immediately sent properly. The problem is not in the `galleryMeta` array of objects if I set the `Title` in `galleryMeta` to a random number everything works. All the variables that I'm using in the JavaScript code are properly defined. I tried to console.log() every single bit of that code, and all the variables contain their respective proper expected values, always. But strings never get parsed by Axios AJAX at all. It doesn't matter how long the string is or what does it contain, it just won't get past the request. I've also checked the values of that `formData` form with this loop :

```
for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value); 
}
```

And they're all there, assigned properly, just like I wanted. So my question is pretty obvious. How the hell do I parse strings using FormData with Axios in Vue.js? What have I done wrong to make this happen? God, thank anybody who can point out the issue in this. Thank you!

Comment: You said `formData.append('title', '20');` is working properly, but `'20'` also a string. Why you think that string is not being passed?

Comment: Check the answer from Quentin which resolved the issue. And yes '20' is also a string but that worked for some odd reason... My guess is that it was interpreted by JSON as an integer automatically somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $id = json_decode($_POST['id']);
> ```

It works if it is an integer because an integer is valid JSON.

It would also work if the string you were sending was `null`, `false`, `"foo"` (yes, with the quotes), or any other valid JSON.

You are sending a FormData object which serializes to a multipart/form-data request body. **This is not JSON**

Do not try to process it as JSON.

**Do not** use `file_get_contents("php://input")`; **Do** use `$_POST` and `$_FILES`

**Do not** use `json_decode`; **Do** just use the values from `$_POST` and `$_FILES`

---

*Aside*: **Do not** specify `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` as this is missing the mandatory `boundary` parameter. The browser will add the right `Content-Type` header automatically when it receives the FormData object.

Comment: Probably also need to change the default axios post content-type

Comment: @charlietfl — No. The default one is fine. Overriding it may, as I was editing into my answer while you commented, break it!

Comment: No way you're completely right! At first I did not use json_decode for this but I was facing some other issues and upon troubleshooting them multiple people pointed out that you first have to decode it from a JSON format (and I'm not talking about a case in which JSON was parsed originally and decoded afterwards). I've spend so long trying to fix this! Thank you so much for your help marking this as an answer immediately once I can!